# How do I call Vue.set from within a .vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am attempting to convert some code into the .vue format, and when I call this Vue.set line, I get

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined"
```

I'm not clear on the differences between the different ways to create Vue objects, but I'm not sure how to get a reference to Vue alive in my .vue component.

How can I call Vue.set, or do the same functionality, from within a .vue component?

**More info:**

I am attempting to use code from this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/itslit/pen/gvKrMY).

In this example, rather than use a .vue file and have a ,  and  section, it has an index.html file that includes an index.js file and a style.css file.

In the javascript file, you see

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    val: "x"
  },
...
shuffleDeck() {
  Vue.set(arg1, arg2, arg3) // A call to Vue.set happens here
 }
...
```

Vue.set works here, in the docs I see that this function lets the property remain "reactive", so it is likely necessary and can't be replaced by a simple assignment.

Comment: Can you post your .vue file?

Comment: Related: [this.$store is undefined in components](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/409)

Comment: try this ```this.$set()```

Comment: this.$set did the trick - Thank you